# decimal formatting pattern in Java

Tags: java

I want format this number using java :  1546521.23 to 1 546 521.23
for exemple when i format this number 70000.0 it output 7 00 00

I tried this pattern but not work :

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("### ###,##");
```

Comment: If you read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), you'll see that `,` is a *grouping separator*, and `.` is the *decimal separator*. Change format to `"### ###.##"`

Comment: thanks a lot andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [DecimalFormat documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning
.       Number      Yes         Decimal separator or monetary decimal separator
,       Number      Yes         Grouping separator
```

Change code to

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("### ###.##");
```

The comma needs to be replaced with a period.